# Center TextView below ImageView

Tags: android, xml

i'm having some issues centering a TextView below a ImageView in my XML, so i'm curious wether it is possible.

Here's some sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

--- Lots of Code ---

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container_seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/seekbar_leftball"
            android:layout_below="@id/seekbar_leftball"
            android:text="@string/swipe_filter_seekBar_job"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/seekbar_leftball"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
            android:src="@drawable/seekbar_ball"
            android:tint="@color/red"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see i can fix it the left of the ImageView, but i cant find anyway to center it.

Comment: Why don't you use `LinearLayout` with orientation vertical.

Comment: you can set textview property  android:layout_centerInParent="true"

Comment: Because i thought the best way of going about it was using a Relative Layout and having them being placed in "relation" to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView5" android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New Text"
                    android:id="@+id/textView5" android:gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

### Result :

[image]

Comment: Thanks to your answer i was able to modify it slightly to fix my issue.

Answer (score 4):

There are far too many useless views in the solution given. Try this one instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView5" 
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use text view with drawables

```
yourextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(_left, _top, _right, _bottom);
```

Comment: In XML layout: `android:drawableLeft="..."` (drawableTop|Right|Bottom).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
     />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo2"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/logo2"

        android:text="AAAAAAA"
        android:textStyle="bold"
/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```